# how to use HTML in servlets?

Tags: java, html, servlets, frontend, front-controller

I'm interested in the front controller servlet:

https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/frontController.html

I'd like to stick to servlet as much as possible, but am not terribly keen on using a multitude of `system.out` commands to print html.

How would I use "fragments" of `html`, stored literally as `foo.html` and `bar.html`, for different servlets to mix-and-match.

*Yes, this a poorly researched question as it stands.  I'll add research too it, only looking for general information please.*

Comment: [`RequestDispatcher.include(ServletRequest, ServletResponse)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#include(javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse))

Comment: To be honest, you usually use HTML in JSPs rather than Servlets.

Comment: [JSPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages) were designed to solve this problem.